# Automatic constraints to storyboard and xib in XCode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I was just trying to learn Autolayout in XCode 6. But I noticed a strange change in the XCode 6 that is whenever I drag and drop a button (or any UI element) on a xib the XCode isn't automatically adding the constraints to the button. However I do remember this facility was there in the previous versions of XCode. But in XCode 6 I had to explicitly add the constraints to the UI element. Here are the images of what happens in previous version of Xcode 6 and previous version of Xcode .[image: in XCode 6]

[image: In previous version of XCode]

There we can see in XCode 6 no constraints have been added by default but however in previous version of XCode constraint was added by default.

So it would be helpful if you guys let me know if there's a way to enable the feature of adding constraints by default in XCode 6 or is it the way XCode 6 ways where we need to add constraints manually?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the constraints automatically while editing was done in Xcode 4, and it was a disaster. Every time you moved a view, it broke something.

As of 5, any missing constraints will be added at compile time to your views. If you select a view and look in the size inspector, it will tell you this. See [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/10/autolayout-in-interface-builder-xcode-5-dot-1/) for more details on constraints and interface builder.

Answer (score 4):

With the introduction of size classes, to have a universal storyboard for both iPhone and iPad, setting the constraints automatically wouldn't make much sense for me.

You can ask Xcode to resolve auto layout issues for you by pressing the [image: resolve auto layout issues] (Resolve Auto Layout Issues) button in the lower right of the Interface Builder window and choosing “Add Missing Constraints”. The added constraints will fix the subviews relative to their superviews.

[image: add missing constraints]

Comment: Thanks @RobMayoff for adding the screenshots!